# PCB outdoor moisture effect and protection

Tags: troubleshooting

I have been working on a project that requires me to place a pcb outdoor for days to collect data. It has been done 3 times already, and all have failed with unknown reasons. First I thought my battery is bad, and second time I thought it could be low temperature, third time I thought my circuit is bad. I have done extensive tests and eliminated all the above hypotheses.

What could be problem? My circuit has some very high resistance critical resistor components. Could this be the cause? but I have use hot glue to cover all those components all those times.

What are the precautions and methods to run an outdoor small project for about 1 week?

Comment: You really need to provide more details about your "system" and how it failed. Was there smoke involved... or just the recorded numbers did not match what you expected? A whole spectrum of unknowns.

Comment: Have you considered dew point? If dew settles on the 'hot glue' it can easily skew resistances of a few megohms. Perhaps put most of the electronics (and batteries) in an IP66 box and keep them warm and dry. This is often done in security camera enclosures. You may then need to bring your sensors out the box and protect them somehow. What are you measuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick answer is conformal coating. It places a barrier between your board and the elements.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_coating

http://www.humiseal.com/conformal-coating/

Another could be potting the board. That is usually done more for vibration and shock rather than environmental.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potting_(electronics)

Look into conformal coating in my opinion. Also stick it in an enclosure if you do not already do that.

Comment: Think very hard about conformal coating. It's never as easy as it sounds.

Comment: I use nail polish as conformal coating. tested and works even frozen.

Answer (score 7):

> I have done extensive tests and eliminated all the above hypotheses.

You are very sure of yourself, especially for someone that isn't sure what they are doing.  Good troubleshooting includes keeping open the possibility that *you* screwed up.  From your report of what might have gone wrong the first three times, this is a definite possibility.  From your own description, it's pretty clear you don't have the expertise to decide that the three other problems have been "eliminated".  That's the kind of arrogance that blinds you from seeing the real problem.  Debugging must always be done with a humble attitude.

It is possible that environmental conditions caused failure.  Of course that depends on what the environmental condition were.  You mention cold as a possibility.  How cold?  How was the board protected?  What temperature range was it subjected to?  Could moisture have condensed onto the board?  Could bugs have crawled in?

You mention both cold and battery as causes of failure you considered, but apparently independently.  Batteries are more susceptible to low temperatures than most other components.  The battery may work fine powering your circuit on your bench, and the circuit may work fine in a cold chamber while powered from a external source.  However, put the two together and it may not work so well anymore.

A more detailed answer requires a more detailed question.